# Handling Success and Error API responses in Logic Apps workflow

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am bulding a Logic Apps workflow and I need to handle 2 different type of responses returned back by a 3rd API service by using an if condition.

The API response in case of the API being able to process the data correctly looks pretty much like this:

`{ "Key": “AA11-AA11-AA11-AA11", "Geocode":true, "Addresses": [   {   "Address":"", "Address1":"Sageweg 27", "Address2":"Neuenburg", "Address3":"", "Address4":"" }, {   "Address":"", "Address1":"Schubartstr. 111", "Address2":"Bietigheim-Bissingen", "Address3":"74321", "Address4":"" } ] }`

while in case of "error" looks like this:

`{ "Number": 18, "Description": "Missing or invalid parameters", "Cause": "A required parameter was not supplied of the value of a parameter cannnot be converted into the right type.", "Resolution": "Check the parameters passed and their values against the specification for this service." }`

where 18 is just of the possible error scenarios.

How can I set the workflow in terms of actions, and consequently the If condition to discriminate between success and "error" response?

This is what I have so far.

[image]

I've tried to build 2 Parse JSON actions, manaing the success and error paylods scenarios, in parallel, but the workflow takes ages in running, and I also found it tricky to manage the fact that in the success scenario the response is an array, while in the error it's an object, and also not all fields are optional, so this solution looked not the cleanest one to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the success or failure responses as shown below-

[image]

- For testing purpose, I am sending both success and failure payload manually while invoking the workflow.
- Here I have generated a combined schema for both success and failed responses which is being used in **Parse JSON** action.

[image]

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "Addresses": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "Address": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Address1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Address2": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Address3": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Address4": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        },
        "Cause": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Description": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Geocode": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "Key": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Number": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "Resolution": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

- In **Condition** action, I am verifying whether **`Key`** property is null or not. You can use any property which is unique in success and failure payload.

[image]

- With this configuration, I am able to get the expected response.

**Success**-

[image]

**Failure**-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've followed your comment, so I am parsing only the error response and adding a check in the condition to see if Number is equal to null. So, if that's the case, I can keep going with the data processing. This works fine when I receive the error payload, but as soon as the API endpoint is able to process the data, and returns back the success payload, the check condition fails cause it can't find the field as specified in the expression.

The expression I'm using is body(<whatever>)?['body']['Number'], which again, it works fine with the "error" payload scenario.

Comment: You should not use body twice if you are fetching the Number property from Parse_JSON action. You can assign the value of the same expression in a variable and check what is the output you are getting in case of success response. In this way, you can determine why its not working for success payload

Comment: Verify the value of the same expression in both the scenarios by using a variable, you will get to know the issue.